# How can I set correct bitrate for my Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

As per question I just bought `Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter`, specifically [TP-LINK TL-WDN4800 N900](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B007GMPZ0A/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) - which should reach *450* Mbps.

I'm running on kernel `Linux scv 4.10.0-40-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 15:37:44 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and when I try to find the available bitrates I get:

```
ema@scv:~$ sudo iwlist wlp2s0 bitrate
wlp2s0    unknown bit-rate information.
          Current Bit Rate=54 Mb/s
```

I tried to manually set it to *300* Mbps via `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 rate 300M`, but it really doesn't sort any desired effect.

I am connecting to a [Netgear N600](https://www.amazon.co.uk/NETGEAR-DGND3700-100UKS-Wireless-Router-Connections/dp/B004TR5HF8/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_107_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=B3N5BBAF0B2XCRX5K8ES) and the mode of the 5GHz network is set to 300Mbps; this device is ~3m away from my pc and the signal is *good* I guess (only 3 5GHz access points on channel 36):

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"M4yb3_n0tX"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 84:1B:5E:36:9C:22   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=18 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:133   Missed beacon:0
```

My `sudo lspci -vv -s 02:00.0` produces (apologies for long output):

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at f7b00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Expansion ROM at f7b20000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <1us, L1 <8us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <2us, L1 <64us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [300 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

What should I do next? I'd like to achieve *300* Mbps, do you think it'll be possible?

I have tested by transferring files to a pc linked on the same router via Ethernet (1000 *Mbps*), and the best upload speed (Wireless to Ethernet) is around *24* Mbps, whilst the best download speed (Ethernet to Wireless) is around *32* Mbps (it's worth noting that when I connect both PCs Ethernet to Ethernet I reach *1000* Mbps without any sweat).
Is the router which needs changing?

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: 802.11n and 802.11ac require that WMM be enabled, and, if encryption is required, they have to use WPA2 (AES-CCMP). If those aren’t available, you’re stuck at 802.11a and 802.11g rates (54Mbps). Please update your question to include information about how you have WMM and security configured on your AP and client.

Comment: What is WMM? I know I'm using WPA2 (AES though, not AES-CCMP). Any idea how to confirm? In case, this is driven by the access point, right?

Comment: WMM is QoS for Wi-Fi. It was standardized as 802.11e if I recall correctly, but many products still call it WMM. Just like many products just say “AES” rather than the more specific “AES-CCMP”. You must enable these things on the AP and on clients as well, although most easy-to-use clients have these things enabled by default and set to follow what the AP allows. But Linux tends to be a bit more “DIY” than that.

Comment: Please feel free to point me to any doc/website Linux/Ubuntu specific, happy to read and document myself...

Comment: I found those settings and enabling/disabling didin't make any difference. Updating the *firmware* of the access point did the trick (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is very simple: **one can't, one has to rely on drivers and firmware (of both NIC and access point) to do *the right thing***.

Apparently with (relatively) recent Linux kernels one *can't* setup the `bitrate`, but has to rely on the driver/firmware of the [card](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B007GMPZ0A/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) to get it right.

I have just updated the firmware of my [access point](https://www.amazon.co.uk/NETGEAR-DGND3700-100UKS-Wireless-Router-Connections/dp/B004TR5HF8/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_107_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=B3N5BBAF0B2XCRX5K8ES) and now this is the output of `iwconfig wlp2s0`:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"M4yb3_n0tX"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 84:1B:5E:36:9C:22   
          Bit Rate=216 Mb/s   Tx-Power=18 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:112   Missed beacon:0
```

Please note that *bitrate* is *216* Mbps. Real world measurements are now: upload speed *67* Mbps, download speed *140* Mbps. Definitely an improvement, still a far cry from the *1000* Mbps of wired Ethernet...

Update: now that I'm using the 5GHz connection, the `Bit Rate` oscillates between 216 Mb/s to 300 Mb/s depending at which time I connect during the day (I guess it's got to do with other potential interferences of neighbouring networks).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is off-topic but I guess you have the same issue as mine: Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter has a low transmit (upload) rate under linux.

According to #69 of [Ubuntu bug #1670041](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1670041):

> The low throughput with transmit TCP streams on ath10k should be fixed
>   with this mac80211 commit:
>
> mac80211: Adjust TSQ pacing shift
>
> https://git.kernel.org/linus/36148c2bbfbe50c50206b6f61d072203c80161e0
>
> Apparently v4.16-rc5 was the first release to have that commit.

Upgrading your Linux kernel to a newer version could fix this (Linux 4.17.14 in my case).